# Amplitude and cut off of gaussian distribution

Tags: python, random, gaussian

I want to generate random errors in Python assigned to value a with gaussian distribution, known the information that the:

amplitude=72.e-3, cutoff=3

I tried to use:

```
Random_error: a *= (1 + amplitude* random(cutoff))
```

I got the error:

```
" Random.random() takes no arguments (1 given)"
```

I want to be sure that the formula I am using to set the amplitude and cut off for gaussian distribution is the right one.

Best Regard

Comment: `random.random` generates a number between 0 and 1. Did you mean `random.gauss`? The typical parameters for a gaussian/normal distribution is mu/mean and sigma/variance. What exactly do you mean with amplitude and cutoff here?

Comment: The Amplitude is the height of the center of the distribution in Y units., And the cut off is the tail bound of the distribution @tobias_k

Comment: I used random,gauss(amplitude, cut) but i got the error "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'gauss'"@tobias_k

Comment: could you use more conventional terms?  I don't find "amplitude", "cutoff", or "tail bound" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: So you mean that the probability for the mean value should be 0.072 and any value smaller than -3 or greater than 3 should be capped at those values?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes this what i meant

Comment: Not sure, I guess you have to "stretch" the typical normal distribution with an "amplitude" by using a really high sigma (see the illustration on Wikipedia for an example with sigma=5). But with such high standard deviation, _most_ values will be above or below the cutoff, which does not make much sense. Are you sure that's what you are supposed to do?

Comment: @tobias_k I checked now and the amplitude should be a value that i multiplied by the gaussian distribution, now the only information i have is the cut, should i in this case consider the mean to be zero in the function random.gauss(mu, cutoff) ?

Comment: You can use [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html). But the amplitude shouldn't matter since the CDF needs to be normalized to `1` anyway.

Comment: @a_guest which one of the truncnorm functions should i use are the parameters a and b represent the cut value ?

Comment: @ely66 You can use `x = truncnorm.rvs(left_cutoff, right_cutoff, scale=std_dev_of_distribution, size=number_of_data_points)`.

Comment: @tobias_k Density is not probability. Since Gaussian is a continuous distribution, the probability of getting any particular value is zero. You can only talk about non-zero probabilities for ranges, not for points.